# MS Excel SDK issue: Can't use ToolTip in Tree-View control in XLL add-in

Tags: winapi, controls, treeview, excel-addins, xll

I have a dialog window with a Tree-View control where the user can drag the items to rearrange the tree.

It looks and behaves differently when it is used in an executable and in an MS Excel add-in XLL.

It looks like this during a drag operation when used in an executable(this is the desired look):

[image]

But when I use the same dialog in an MS Excel add-in XLL(where it is displayed when user selects a command) it looks like this(notice the missing tooltip, and icons for expanded items):

[image]

What could be causing this? Is there a way I can make the dialog look like the way it does when used in an executable?

---

I suspect it has to do with the ComCtl32.dll version, as the following returns version 6.16 when called from the executable, but 5.82 when called from XLL:

```
HINSTANCE hinstDll = LoadLibrary(lpszDllName);
DLLGETVERSIONPROC pDllGetVersion =
    (DLLGETVERSIONPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstDll, "DllGetVersion");
```

I have the following manifest in the .cpp file.

```
#include <commctrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")

// Enable Visual Style
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_IA64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='ia64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
```

Comment: have correct manifest in dll not enough. need also activate it before create control via `ActivateActCtx`

Comment: @RbMm: I just looked that function up in MSDN. It is under "Isolated Applications and Side-by-side Assemblies", and I browsed through it for a while but it turns out to be a way too advanced topic for me at the moment. I don't understand most of it. Is there a way you can give me an example on how to use that function related to the problem I described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we in *DLL* have resource of type `RT_MANIFEST` with name `ISOLATIONAWARE_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID` (note that for *EXE* need use `CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID`) the loader create activation context for our *DLL* (and save it in `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY.EntryPointActivationContext`) but it activate it only before call our *DLL* entry point, and just deactivate it after it return. really - in process we have many *DLLs* - from which *DLL* need activate context ? the system activate activation context from *EXE* only. and from *DLL* - temporary, during call it Entry point. however we need use this activation context (from our *DLL*) during create a window etc.

so strategy is next:

get and save our activation context on *DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH*:

```
// global variables
HANDLE g_hActCtx;
BOOLEAN g_bActCtxValid;

case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    //...
    g_bActCtxValid = GetCurrentActCtx(&g_hActCtx) != FALSE;
    //...
```

when we need create window, dialog, etc - we need activate saved context:

```
ULONG_PTR Cookie;
if (ActivateActCtx(g_hActCtx, &Cookie))
{
    CreateWindowExW(..);
    DeactivateActCtx(0, Cookie);
}
```

and finally, on *DLL* unload - release context:

```
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    if (g_bActCtxValid)ReleaseActCtx(g_hActCtx);
```

---

note that this already not once answered here - for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25271493/6401656). but with one difference - in all other solutions used `CreateActCtx` api (with `dwFlags = ACTCTX_FLAG_HMODULE_VALID | ACTCTX_FLAG_RESOURCE_NAME_VALID, lpResourceName = ISOLATIONAWARE_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID, hModule = &__ImageBase`) - this call create activation context **again** for our *DLL*. but i instead this prefer use already created by system activation context for our *DLL* (this is current context inside *DllMain*). so not duplicate, but reference already created. `GetCurrentActCtx` instead `CreateActCtx`

Comment: Your solution worked, thank you. But I have a couple of questions, if you don't mind.

Comment: In `DllMain()` we do not create an activation context, but simply make a call to `GetCurrentActCtx()`. Which makes me think, there **already is** a "current active content" when `DllMain()` is called. That much, I understand. But if I don't initialize `g_hActCtx` from `DllMain()`, and instead, I call `GetCurrentActCtx()` from another function in the dll, then activate it, it doesn't work. Why is this? Isn't the "current activation context" the same in another function as it is in `DllMain()`?

Comment: You might have already addressed this question at the beginning of your answer, but I want to make sure that I understand correctly. From your answer, I think the way it works is like this: Dll loader creates and activates the "active context" before calling `DllMain()`. This is the one specified as a compiler directive. Then, after the `DllMain()` ends, loader deactivates(and maybe releases?) it. At that point, the "active context" comes from the module that loaded the dll. Is that correct?

Comment: @Kemal - `Isn't the "current activation context" the same in another function as it is in DllMain()` of course no. before call your dll entry point loader call `ActivateActCtx` which he create personally for your dll (based on resource). and call `DeactivateActCtx` just after `DllMain` return. so in `DllMain` and **only** in `DllMain` the active context is from your *DLL* resource. in another DLL functions it unknown. really - system don know about your exported function called and not special activate your native context

Comment: @Kemal call `GetCurrentActCtx()` and **just** `ActivateActCtx` in place - no sense. you got the current active context and say make it again current active. exist sense call this functions from different places - first from entry point and save. then in another function - you run in arbitrary activation context. and call `ActivateActCtx` change this arbitrary to correct saved

Comment: @Kemal - `Dll loader creates and activates the "active context" before calling DllMain(). This is the one specified as a compiler directive. Then, after the DllMain() ends, loader deactivatesit. At that point, the "active context" comes from the module that loaded the dll. Is that correct?` - yes. you correct understand. the loader create context when it load your dll. and save in `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY.EntryPointActivationContext`. and release it when your dll is unloaded

Comment: Got it. One more question: Assume that I don't have a .manifest file and instead, I have the compiler directive, which is exactly my case. If I `#define ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED 1`, my dialog resources display correctly(say, comctl32.dll version 6.0.0.0 style) without me having to use activate/deactivate any "activation context"s. Why is that?

Comment: In that scenario, even though dialog resources are displayed in v6.0.0.0 style without the need for context activation/deactivation, `MessageBox()` displays a dialog in v5.82 style **unless** I explicitly activate "activation context". Is that normal?

Comment: @Kemal - this manifest from exe or dll. loader activate and use activation context from exe resource permanent. it can not use it from some dll - because many dlls - from which need use ? so activate it only temporary. if exe have needed to you manifest - you can not have and activate context from dlls. and instead linker directives, you can yoursel set manifest in resource: `ISOLATIONAWARE_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST ".manifest"`

Comment: @Kemal - `In that scenario,..` i not complete understand concrete scenario - which manifests in exe and dll. how and when activated context from dll and how dialog/messagebox(modal dialog) created.

Comment: The scenario is this: I do not use a manifest file for the dll, only the compiler directive. I have `ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED 1` defined. I call `DialogBox(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), g_hWndMain, TreeviewDlgProc);` from a function `f()` in the dll, **without activating** any "activation context". IDD_DIALOG1 is displayed in v6-style. After that, in `f()`, I make a call to `MessageBox()`. Again, no activated context. Message box is displayed in v5-style. I haven't changed anything, so why is one dialog displayed in one style, and the other in another?

Comment: @Kemal - read [Specifying a Default Activation Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376607(v=vs.85).aspx) - if you ask how it work - search `ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED` in header files.

Comment: say `#if defined(ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED) && (ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED != 0)
#include "winuser.inl"
#endif /* ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED */`
 and look "winuser.inl"

Comment: @Kemal - so instead `DialogBoxParamW` called `IsolationAwareDialogBoxParamW` (by macro redirection) and look for `IsolationAwareDialogBoxParam` implementation - this is inline

Comment: @Kemal - and look for `winbase.inl ` - when you define `ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED` - all this code included (as inline) to your code and increase size of module. really this is what i paste here `CreateActCtx` + `ActivateActCtx` and function wrap

Comment: Proceeding as you suggested, I just found out why `DialogBox()` is isolation aware, whereas `MessageBox()` is not. It turns out, unlike `DialogBoxParamW()`, macro indirection is skipped for `MessageBoxW()` with the comment `MessageBoxW skipped, as it is a popular C++ member function name.`

Comment: @Kemal - yes, because exist macro for `#define DialogBoxParamW IsolationAwareDialogBoxParamW` (the `DialogBox` is also macro expanded to `DialogBoxParam`) but no macro for `MessageBox`